# How to submit data to CouchDB without AJAX (with a normal form PUT)

Tags: javascript, forms, couchdb

I'm wondering how to submit data to CouchDB without using AJAX.  AJAX is awesome, but there are still some folk who have JavaScript off along with a variety of other reasons not to rely solely on JavaScript.

I'm wondering how to submit data to CouchDB with a normal HTML form submission (POST request).  What do I put in the action attribute?  What should I expect happens to my data?

I tried testing this out myself with little success. I also searched the guide and wiki to no avail.  If there is an article already out there that would rock!

Comment: Here's a library to do simple couch commands. If Couch is hard, use Pillow:
https://github.com/JonathanRys/libraries/tree/master/pillow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [update handlers](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers).

Comment: This is a low quality answer.  As is the risk with link-only answers, the link is now stale.

Comment: The link isn't *dead*, it's *stale*.  The official documentation site has changed.